# I can't edit anything on MSE or network-wide right now: HTTP 500 - "An error occurred submitting the edit."

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, 500-server-error

When I try to edit anything on MSE right now (when I click the "Save edits" button), I get a red box that says:

> An error occurred submitting the edit.

In my console, I see:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/393680/edit-submit/<GUID>

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can reproduce on all sites, whether using inline editor, separate editor page, or even suggested edits on sites where I don't have rep to edit.

Comment: The 10k inline tag editor works, though. Means that mods can still add [tag:status-review] to escalate the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce it on other sites, but (FWIW) not here.

Comment: Possibly related: [why css is not loading in my browser - Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426813/why-css-is-not-loading-in-my-browser) (also 500 errors). And just a moment ago I couldn't load posts on MSO.

Comment: @Glorfindel I can edit here on MSE now, but still not on SO. My adblocker is disabled on Stack Exchange sites (at wjandrea/Makyen).

Comment: we're aware and progressively fixing it across the network - MSE and MSO are done. I'll post an answer when it's all fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had an issue with a deployment today that broke editing across the network - this should now be fixed network-wide.

Comment: what exactly was being deployed?

Comment: @starball A whole bunch of stuff, but the relevant bit was a set of refactoring changes that inadvertently introduced a null reference exception in rate limit checks.